# Get current rowindex from RowFilter include

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, rowfilter

I have filtered a `JTable` with following `RowFilter` and it works fine:

```
RowFilter<AbstractTableModel, Object> rowFilter = new RowFilter<AbstractTableModel, Object>(){
    public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends AbstractTableModel, ? extends Object> entry){
        String cellValue = entry.getValue(0).toString();
        boolean isRowIncluded = cellValue.startsWith(filterText) ? true : false;
        return isRowIncluded;
}
};
```

But I am facing an issue. I have to apply the same filter logic to `TreeTable`. I have a custom table and table model extended from `AbstractTableModel`. I need to filter the rows and show its parents rows (parent rows may not satisfy `isRowIncluded`).

How can I achieve the functionality with my existing row filter?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: question in this form isn't answerable without you SSCCE, please whats boolean isRowIncluded = cellValue.startsWith(filterText) ? true : false;
        return isRowIncluded;, there are two states, indexes JTables view and from 
(Xxx)TableModel

Comment: which treetable (it's not available in core)? Anyway, most probably it doesn't support filtering (nor sorting).

Comment: Finally achieved by using Jide FilterableTableModel.. still wonder why modelIndex is hidden in RowFilter include method